# Why does a child process killed due to a segmentation fault not die immediately?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, signals, segmentation-fault, sigchld

I need to write a C++ code which accepts a certain input and prints the respective output. This code is meant to be run using the Python subprocess module. Regardless of inputs and outputs, I need to make sure that the Python code does not terminate prematurely due to runtime errors the C++ code encounters. The basic nature of the C++ code is as follows

```
int main()
{
  /*The pointer is initialized to NULL to simulate a segmentation fault
    Also the n is meant for simulating input.*/
  int *p=NULL,n;   
  cin>>n;
  cout<<*p<<endl;  //This causes a segmentation fault.
}
```

The Python code which runs it, is as follows:

```
from subprocess import *
from signal import *

def handler(signum,frame):
    raise RuntimeError("Runtime Error")

call(["g++","try.cpp"])
a = Popen(["stdbuf","-i0","-o0","-e0","./a.out"],stdin = PIPE,stdout = PIPE)
try:
    #Handler for signal due to termination of child process
    signal(SIGCHLD,handler)    
    a.stdin.write("1\n")
    temp = a.stdout.readline()
except RuntimeError as e:
    print e
    print a.returncode   

#Returncode of process killed due to SIGSEGV is -11
    if a.returncode == -11:   
        print "Segmentation Fault Occurred"
```

This is the issue. Even though the C++ code experiences a segmentation fault, the signal handler is invoked, the `RuntimeError` is raised, but the returncode of the Popen object is `none`, indicating that the process still lives.
Now if the following change is made to the except block:

```
a.wait()
print a.returncode        
if a.returncode == -11:   
    print "Segmentation Fault Occurred"
```

The issue is resolved. The output shows that the returncode of the Popen object is -11 and "Segmentation Fault Occurred" is printed to the screen.
The exact same happens if I try to simulate a floating point exception due to divide-by-zero.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Programming is brutal. (Y'know, children getting killed and such.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> Popen.wait()
>      Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

So `returncode` is not set until `wait` is called.

Alternately you could perform a non-blocking check to see if process is terminated using `poll`, which would set `returncode` as well if terminated.

> Popen.poll()
>      Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute.

note that you don't really need the `signal` call (not sure if it's portable on Windows). The code could be simplified like this:

```
a = Popen(["stdbuf","-i0","-o0","-e0","./a.out"],stdin = PIPE,stdout = PIPE)
a.stdin.write("1\n")
a.stdin.flush()
temp = a.stdout.readline()
if temp:
    # do something
    print("output "+temp)
else:
    # empty string: recieved process has ended, probably unexpectedly
    # because it should have printed something
    pass

returncode = a.wait()

#Returncode of process killed due to SIGSEGV is -11
if returncode  == -11:   
    print("Segmentation Fault Occurred")
```

note that you have to `a.stdin.flush()` to be sure the input reaches the c++ program.